# Dataset for humans,man and woman?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I am developing a image classifier that classifies animals and humans.I have found lot of images on google but most of them are watermarked.Is there any good dataset of humans-"man and womam separately"- available?

Comment: Have you tried googling "free faces database" (no quotes), or are you looking for full body images?

Comment: @BarryCarter I need full body,for example-man standing in different poses.What I currently did is .I downloaded pics from google and made my own.But its very hard to find all poses so it had affected classification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried ImageNet? There are 14 million images which have been tagged through crowdsourcing.

Here is a search for man:
http://image-net.org/search?q=man